# In WPF How to prevent Controls inside ScrollViewer from expanding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I'm trying to achieve something that sounds pretty simple, in WPF, but just can't get around doing it.
I have a ScrollViewer which contains two GroupBoxes. First one has it's height set to a fixed value, second one would take what's left of the window but have a MinHeight. Each GroupBox contains a DataGrid.

What i'm trying to do is :
The second groupbox should be sized to what's left of the Window and the DataGrid inside of it should be sized to fill the group box and have it's own scrollbar if rows can't all be shown. A scrollbar should appear in the window if i resize the window to be less than GroupBox1.Height+GroupBox2.MinHeight.

The behavior i get now is, the DataGrid in the second groupbox's height grows with the number of lines, thus expanding the Groupbox and having the Scrollviewer's scrollbar show up.

I came up with a little demo-app to show this behavior

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="400"
    Width="500">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Header="test1"
                      Grid.Row="0">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="test2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      MinHeight="50">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            Colors = new List<Color>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
            {
                byte b = (byte)(i * 5);
                Colors.Add(Color.FromRgb(b,b,b));
            }
        }

        private List<Color> _colors;
        public List<Color> Colors
        {
            get
            {
                return _colors;
            }
            set
            {
                _colors = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm getting :

[image: What i'm getting]

What i would want (sorry for the bad photo-manipulation skills) :

[image: What i would want]

Unless, as specified earlier, i resize the window to be smaller than the sum of the group1's fixed size and group2's min size, in which case i want the window's scrollbar.

In which case, i would want it to look like this : (again a mock-up, not an actual screenshot)

[image: Mockup2]

Mind you, the example is pretty simple but the window i'm trying to do it in is much more complex and it makes more sense to have a vertical scrollbar than it does in this example.

Thanks!

Comment: Specify a fixed Height for the ScrollViewer element?

Comment: @mm8 Doing so would make it useless to a resizeable window. Having a small value as ScrollViewer height would make it so that it is always visible and is limiting the space taken by the groups. Having a big value ends up showing the exact same issue.
EDIT: I tried it, just to make sure and the issue is there, even for a small ScrollViewer. The 2nd group expands to the grid's content and i just have less space to scroll and the window's resizing becomes useless.

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue. There is no ScrollViewer on your second picture. So when exactly do you expect this ScrollViewer to show up?

Comment: As mentionned, the ScrollViewer should showup only if i resize my window so that it is too small to show Group1's Height (fixed size) and Group2's MinHeight.

Comment: Then you should set the Height or the MinHeight of the ScrollViewer to Group1.Height + Group2.Height.

Comment: Nop. That doesn't help, my 2nd grid still expands to it's content, thus expanding the 2nd group.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what i would want when the window is resized to be smaller than Grp1.Height+Grp2.MinHeight

Comment: Maybe you need to change the height of the ScrollViewer as the window is resized.

Comment: I fail to see how it is gonna prevent the 2nd grid from growing up, which is the root of the problem. For example, if i set it to 200, the 2nd grid still grows to take all the space it needs to display all of its lines, without showing it's scrollbar, so the ScrollViewer just gets super long...
And also, the ScrollViewer already Fills the window, so it is in fact getting resized with the window, automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply bind the `MaxHeight` property of the second `GroupBox` to the `ActualHeight` of the container of the `ScrollViewer` minus the first `GroupBox`.

Complete example (excluding the code behind which is same as yours.):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApp1:SubtractConverter x:Key="SubtractConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="Root">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox
                Name="Test1"
                Header="test1"
                Grid.Row="0">

                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox
                Header="test2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                MinHeight="250">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"/>

                <GroupBox.MaxHeight>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SubtractConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Root"/>
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Test1"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </GroupBox.MaxHeight>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

```
public class SubtractConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double[] doubles = values.Cast<double>().ToArray();

        double result = doubles[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < doubles.Length; i++)
        {
            result -= doubles[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what the behavior i'm looking for! Thank you so much!
It is more complex than i was expecting, but it's all good. As long as it works properly :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be the easiest solution for your problem but you could do something along this line:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow"
Height="400"
Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HeightConverter x:Key="HeightConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="MainView">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Header="test1"
                  Grid.Row="0">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="test2"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  x:Name="grpBox2"
                  MinHeight="50">
                <GroupBox.Height>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}" ConverterParameter="150">
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="MainView" />
                        <Binding Path="MinHeight" ElementName="grpBox2" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </GroupBox.Height>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And for the converter something like this:

```
public class HeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
        if (values == null || parameter == null || values[0] == null || values[1] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var currentWindowHeight = double.Parse(values[0].ToString());
        var currentMinHeight = double.Parse(values[1].ToString());

        var currentTopWindowHeight = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        var newHeight = currentWindowHeight - currentTopWindowHeight;

        if (newHeight < currentMinHeight)
            newHeight = currentMinHeight;

        return newHeight;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Tested and working-ish, except it doesn't respect the MinHeight wheras Yusuf's solution does. 
Still thanks alot, both your solutions are similar and i will use something inspired by them in my actual app. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. Strange that it does not respect the MinHeight eventhough it specifically checks for it. But anyway glad i could help! Cheers